# How to move UIView when scroll in TableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview, scrollview

In facebook app, when you scroll your TableView down, an UIView on the top will disappear with animation. How can i do this in code, that is, access and modify the Y position of the UIView depend on the contentoffset of tableview's scrollview

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more for those of us who do not use the Facebook app? Should the `UIView` remain fixed for a certain distance of scrolling, then gradually disappear? It sounds like (from your question) that you are assuming `UIView` is a subview of the table view, which would be a lot more work than necessary if it just stays fixed